# Nautilus doesn't differentiate between pdf and doc?

Tags: nautilus

I wanted to sort by file type in Nautilus in 14.04, however I found that pdf, odt, and doc files are all put into the same "Documents" category. Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to show information about the MIME type in Nautilus. PDF files will show as `application/pdf`, ODT files as `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` and DOC files as `application/msword`.

To do this in Ubuntu 14,04, open Nautilus, go to "Edit" -> "Preferences" -> "List Columns" and check the box next to "MIME Type".